# How to prohibit content in element values using XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I want my XSD schema to prohibit certain pieces of content from an element.

Sample XML:

```
<MyElement>This is some valid content.</MyElement>
<MyElement>This content ((( is now allowed )))</MyElement>
```

The pieces of content I want to block are each multiple character strings (ie. not just single characters), like `(((` for example.

I can achieve the restriction with a regex, but it seems <xs:pattern> does not allow look-arounds, and expects to restrict the content by specifying valid values instead of invalid values.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The only way that comes to mind is to use an XSD 1.1 assertion such as

`<xs:assert test="not(matches(., 'some-pattern'))"/>`

but of course that will only work with an XSD 1.1 processor.

Comment: Thank you for that.  Unfortunately we're using libxml2 which only supports XSD 1.0 at this time.